# Suppose f(x) is an odd function. Prove that g(x) = |f(x)| is an even function.

Tags: functions, absolute-value

Suppose f(x) is an odd function. Prove that g(x) = |f(x)| is an even function. 
I understand that an odd function is where f(-x) = -f(x), and an even function is where f(-x) = f(x), but am struggling with actually proving the question.

Comment: What is $g(-x)$?

Comment: Note that $|-f(x)| = |f(x)|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(-x) = |f(-x)| = |-f(x)| = |f(x)| = g(x)$. So $g$ is even.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I just had put in g(x) badly.

Answer (score 1):

You've nearly answered your own question in the OP. :)

We know $f$ is an odd function, so $f(-x) = -f(x)$.  Thus we have $|f(-x)| = |-f(x)| = f(x)$.

In particular, notice that $|f(-x)| = |f(x)|$.  We conclude that $|f(x)|$ is an even function.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in the comment to @LAcarguy, I was struggling to use the g(x) in a proper proof. This does clear it up aswell though!

Comment: Sure thing!  If you're good to go, remember to accept one of our answers (click the check mark) so your question no longer shows up as unanswered for us.